# Eiffel compilation through Makefile and `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` generating an error

Tags: makefile, dpkg, eiffel

Am trying to create a debian package of my Eiffel application.

Either `make` or `make -j4` (which is the called one from dpkg-buildpackage) within the root structure does the job **without error**

but **when called from** `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` which calls the Makefile it exits with an error

```
In file included from big_file_C7_c.c:40:0:
lo322.c: In function ‘inline_F425_4447’:
lo322.c:97:5: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     syslog(arg1, arg2);
     ^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

My makefile for info is as following:

```
#Build variables                                                 
MY_EC = $(shell which ec)                                                                         
BUILT_TARGET = EIFGENs/$(TARGET_NAME)/F_code/$(APP_NAME)

# This target will compile all files
all: build


build:                                                     
#       Checks eiffel compiler     
#       @echo "MY EC IS: ${MY_EC}"
        @if [ -z "${MY_EC}" ]; then
                echo "Compiler not found";
        else           
                echo "Eiffel compiler found";
        fi               
#       Compilation                        
        echo '---------->finalizing'                                    
        ec -finalize -config $(APP_NAME).ecf -target $(TARGET_NAME) || (echo "last command failed $$="; exit 1)
        cd $(FINAL_EXE_DIR); \
        echo '---------->Finish freezing';\
        finish_freezing || (echo "A problem occured during finish_freezing!!!"; exit 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the feature `c_logging_write_log` of the class `LOG_WRITER_SYSTEM` in *EiffelStudio 18.11 and earlier* that makes the following call:

```
syslog($priority, $msg);
```

Replacing it with

```
syslog($priority, "%s", (char *) $msg);
```

(in `$ISE_EIFFEL/library/runtime/logging/writers/log_writer_system.e`) and recompiling the system (from scratch, if the logging library is marked as read-only) should fix the problem.

Comment: yes, the "problem" is that the debian package does a clean before compiling which for me makes sense. Into my clean target I remove the EIFFGENs and the generated LOG_WRITER_SYSTEM is removed, where can I find the template|file where I can do the modification so that the good one is replaced...?

Comment: @Pipo I suggest to edit the class `LOG_WRITER_SYSTEM` found in your installation of EiffelStudio. It should be in `.../library/runtime/logging/writers/log_writer_system.e`.

Comment: Still a warning: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘EIF_POINTER {aka void *}’ [-Wformat=]
     syslog(arg1, "%s", arg2);

Comment: @Pipo For that you can add a type cast: `(char *) $msg`.

Comment: seems that bug hasn't been pulled up to 18.11... had to replace it again after updating

Comment: @Pipo The issue is fixed in the versions after 18.11.